# What's the shortest way of saying "$20 billion worth of U.S. bonds"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

What's the shortest way of saying "$20 billion worth of U.S. bonds"? I was thinking it was "$20 billion of U.S. bonds", but I am thinking worth is necessary. Is it? Can we shorten it even more and why?

Comment: If I had $20 billion **in** US bonds, I'd be quite happy.

Answer (score 1):

"$20 billion of US bonds" is fine. It's already obvious that $20 billion is the value, so "worth" is not necessary.

You can't shorten it further without impairing readability or leaving out some information. You could abbreviate "$20 billion" to "$20G", but some readers wouldn't understand. If you don't care that it's in US bonds, you could just say "$20 billion". Otherwise, "$20 billion of US bonds" is the best you can do.

Comment: The problem with brevity in describing financial instruments is that misleading figures may be produced. In the case of bonds that are traded they will have been issued at one price, may be redeemable in the future for another price, and on any particular day trade at yet another price - possibly a tiny fraction of the issue price. So, for the sake of clarity, you had better say US bonds worth $20 billion in today's market, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @JeremyC: I almost mentioned the possibility of face value ≠ market value, but decided it was probably irrelevant. The OP is asking for brevity, not precision.

Comment: Yes. I realise that, but there are cases in which imprecise brevity can be seriously misleading. In the 1970s, for instance I could have held £1 million of UK Government War Loan. Would I have been a millionaire? No. It was worth £200k.